# What is the probability of getting the first red marble at the fifth try?

Tags: probability

The problem sounds like this: There are 8 white marbles and 10 red marbles in a bowl. Each action consists of taking one marble from the bowl and putting it back into the bowl. The question is: What is the probability that at the FIFTH time you are taking a marble out of the bowl, this would be the FIRST red marble that you took?

I tried to simplify a bit this problem and thinking only of the SECOND time. Therefore, I think the answer would be 8/18 * 10/18. (The probability of having the first one white and the second one red.) Could be this extended to the FIFTH case as well? (8/18)^4 * 10/18? I am not sure if I am missing something or not.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, your computation is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I'm posting a similar problem if you can take a look.